# HTTP Error 500.0 - ASP.NET Core IIS hosting failure (in-process) in Dot net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, nopcommerce-4.3

**I had checked all possible ways to Solve this error like

1. installed dot net core 3.1 runtime environment
2. set AspNetCoreHostingModel as OutProcess
   But still getting this error when  i'm trying to set my Default Nopcommerce 4.3 Project  on IIs to run on it .
   Please Help as I already spent too much time to solve this error**

[image]

Comment: Check the IIS Event Viewer for errors to get more Info.  You are getting an exception in the IIS.  The issue may be you are trying to access the IIS file system and do not have the credentials to access the file system.  Did you do a publish and install the setup.exe folder?  A Net application will only run on a deploy machine if the version of Net is same on both build and remote machine.  So the core version has to be the same.  You can also add to the body of the response the Stack Trace for the exception so you can determine the exact cause of issue.

Comment: @jdweng I m not publishing. it's default nopcommerce 4.3 so i'm installing it on iis as a  localhost

Comment: What do you mean by "My Default Nopcommerce 4.3 Project"?  It sound like you are doing two things 1) Installing Nopcommerce 4.3 2) Installing a c# app which calls Nopcommerce 4.3.

Comment: Yeah I'm Installing Nopcommerce 4.3 Project which is build in dot net core 3.1  on IIS

Comment: I think there is something wrong with Net 3.1.14 (see https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1?force_isolation=true).  You need to download a compatible runtime version of Core 3.1 that you built with.  I've answered in the last couple of weeks a few similar question to yours.  If you look at link for 3.1.13 it says " On Windows, we recommend installing the Hosting Bundle, which includes the .NET Runtime and IIS support."  It doesn't say same for 3.1.14.  You may want to try an earlier version of Core 3.1.  I think there is something missing in 3.1.14.

Comment: It looks like in 3.1.13 something was missing and the kludge was to download two packages.  In 3.1.14 it looks like Microsoft attempted to fix the issue and again failed.  Download the patches : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-april-2021-updates/?force_isolation=true

Comment: Thanks @jdweng .Exactly it was my main issue..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I struggled a lot to  find out this problem's solution . after 4 5 days research, I come to know the exact solution. Kindly follow all the below steps, definatly it will work for Nopcommerce 4.3 Issue using dotnetcore 3.1 or normal  dotnetcore 3.1 project.

**Step1 :**  check dotnet version and sdk  using cmd
[image]

**Step 2:**  add the IISUSER or you can also give Everyone permission  to the main folder

**Step 3:** If it is nopcommerce 4.3 project then configure the path

[image]
and paste below folders in **bin->debug->netcoreapp3.1**

**App_Data,Views,wwwroot,Plugins,Themes,logs,Areas/Views,web.config**

**Note :** this is the main solution after adding the web.config under **bin->debug->netcoreapp3.1**

```
<aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\Nop.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" hostingModel="InProcess">
```

[image]

**Note :** If  you have configured your site already in  iis, then do  the last step
reset the iis using cmd.
open cmd as administrator and run  command  **iisreset**
[image]

I hope  this will resolve your all issues

Answer (score 6):

The same thing happened to me in .net core 3.1.
In my case some server roles and features were missing

Checking the Application Event Log I found the error '0x8007023e'
[image: AspNetCore Module V2]

Checking the System Event Log I found a WAS (Windows Process Activation Service) communication error:
[image: WAS (Windows Process Activation Service) communication error]

Then I installed the following roles and features:
[image: Roles and Features, WAS]

[image]

Also I reinstalled ASP.NET Core Module *(is a native IIS module that plugs into the IIS pipeline, allowing ASP.NET Core applications to work with IIS)*

Finally I had to reassign the app pool to the site, and everything worked (I'm using InProcess model)

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET Core 3.1 Runtime (v3.1.6) - Windows Hosting Bundle

You can download it from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.6-windows-hosting-bundle-installer).

Comment: Still same issue is there

Comment: It solved my problem for .net core 3.1

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this issue today, and used [Rick Strahl's Blog Post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Jan/14/ASPNET-Core-IIS-InProcess-Hosting-Issues-in-NET-Core-31#additional-debugging-detail) on the subject to troubleshoot.

Ultimately, using the **Windows Event Log** proved to be the most helpful at finding the actual error, which for me was a malformed line in the `web.config`.  This was targeting a `.exe` rather than the `.dll` for the app (published as framework-dependent instead of standalone).  As such, IIS was unable to even do anything, and wasn't even logging to STDOUT or give a more descriptive error.

An abbreviated example is that I had this:

```xml
<aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApp.exe" ... />
```

Instead of this:

```xml
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
            arguments=".\MyApp.dll" ... />
```

Since the `.exe` didn't exist, IIS was throwwing an error.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP Error 500.0 - ASP.NET Core IIS hosting failure (in-process) in Dot net core 3.1

Solution :

Click on the Project Properties

Select Hosting Model "**Out of Process**" Try this.

[image: Project settings]

Comment: This happened here when migrating from .net 5 to .net 6

Comment: This solved the problem for me, I had switched from "Any CPU" to "x86" which triggered this issue, in my case.  Alas, I still have other problems to solve that are not related to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you've installed the hosting bundle this error is often a permission issue. Since this is the first question that comes up on google, I wanted to add more information on how to debug if the problem is indeed a permission issue.

- Look in the Event viewer under Applications. You may see an Error for source ***IIS AspNetCore Module V#*** stating;

  - *Unexpected exception: status: Access is denied.: "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe"*
- *Right-click your site in IIS -> Manage Website -> Advanced Settings*.

  - Note the *name* of your application pool.
- In IIS under the *Application Pools* section, note the *Identity* of the application pool with the matching *name*.
- Right click *C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet* (or whatever folder the event viewer is complaining about) and select Properties.

  - On the *Security tab -> Edit -> Add* the appropriate *Application Pool Identity* as a user with permissions.

Comment: Or add a parent user of application pool identity

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this issue today when migrating to .NET 6.
I tried different suggestions i have read here and elsewhere, but without any success, till i saw the answer of @Kurtis.
I saw the errors in the even log, but in my case it was the path to the .exe and not the DLL.

[image]

[image]

As you can see this was pointing to the old net5 folder. I changed the path in the config file and voila!
I had to recycle the app pool was used, iisreset was not enough!

Thank you Kurtis!

Answer (score 1):

If the .net SDKs are installed properly, yet not throwing the same error. Then please check if you selected a dedicated apppool for  and that selected to CLI version to No managed code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was web.config file. My site was hosted as an application inside another website (app folder). Adding "location" tag with **inheritInChildApplication="false"** resolved the issue for me.

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- other configs -->
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had incorrect path starting with *"\bin\net6.0\app.exe"*. IIS maps it as
*"C:\bin\net6.0\app.exe"*
. It should be *"**.**\bin\net6.0\app.exe"* or *"bin\net6.0\app.exe"*.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved with the following steps;

> Right Click on Project > Properties > Web > Project Url change https -> http