# Why Is my Blazor Server App Showing A 403.14 Forbidden Error?

Tags: .net, iis, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

On two different servers, I have deployed a Blazor Server App using .NET 6.0 and everything ran without an issue.  Then I had an update - a different update for each server - and I started to get a 403.14 Forbidden error.

I did some digging and was led to attempt to copy the web.config that VS 2021 created on my computer during debug and then to include that in the main folder of my deployed app.  When I do that, I get a HTTP Error 500.0 - ASP.NET Core IIS hosting failure (in-process) error.  I tried the steps I found in this question - [HTTP Error 500.0 - ASP.NET Core IIS hosting failure (in-process) in Dot net core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297354/http-error-500-0-asp-net-core-iis-hosting-failure-in-process-in-dot-net-core) - but that did not resolve anything.

I ensured that the server app is running the correct App Pool, I bounced the box - nothing is working.  I even spun up a new server, deployed the app and it ran fine - until I pushed out the exact same code again and then I got the errors above.  I redeployed the .NET 6 hosting package, separately re-installed just the .NET 6.0 runtime.  I am completely stuck.

Has anybody had this issue?

Here is my web.config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\vBear-Frontend.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: First you might want to enable Faild Request Logging to see where the error is coming from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: My gut feeling says it has something to do with the application folder permissions

Comment: Taks a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631211/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-conte

Comment: [Using Failed Request Tracing Rules to Troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr) is the best choice.

Comment: Thank you all for your help but nothing has worked outside of changing the deployment to Enable ReadyToRun compilation.  This works but then I lose the ability to make any isolated CSS changes without a complete redeployment.

Comment: You need more detailed information to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Sasha - thank you!  I went through the suggestions and turned off a bunch of extraneous Windows Features and that did the trick!  I have no clue how to promote your comment to an answer to provide you credit.